# Saving page state mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

I am struggling to see how to save a page state without making a session var.
I have a page with a button which changes the state of the page, on post it is possible that the view returns, but in the wrong state. Ive tried ViewBag and this can not be set in java scope. I need a solution to save the value of AuthType..

```
@model Trakman_Portal_Administration.Models.Connection
```

@{

```
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
var conStringType = ViewBag.conStringType;
```

}

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

 <script type='text/javascript'>

var authType = 1

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(authType);
    if (authType == 0) {

        $("#usernameLabel").hide();
        $("#usernameField").hide().find('input:text').val("");

        $("#passwordLabel").hide();
        $("#passwordField").hide().find('input:text').val("");

        //$("#initialCatalogLabel").show();
        //$("#initialCatalogField").show();

        document.getElementById("button1").textContent = "Intergrated";
        authType = 1;
    }
    else {

        $("#usernameLabel").show();
        $("#usernameField").show();
        $("#passwordLabel").show();
        $("#passwordField").show();
        //$("#initialCatalogLabel").hide();
        //$("#initialCatalogField").hide();

        document.getElementById("button1").textContent = "SQL Authentication";
        authType = 0;
    }

    $("button").click(function () {

        //$("#usernameField").attr("value","");
        //$("#passwordField").attr("value","");


        if (authType == 0) {

            $("#usernameLabel").hide();
            $("#usernameField").hide().find('input:text').val("");

            $("#passwordLabel").hide();
            $("#passwordField").hide().find('input:text').val("");

            //$("#initialCatalogLabel").show();
            //$("#initialCatalogField").show();

            document.getElementById("button1").textContent = "Intergrated";
            authType = 1;

        }
        else {

            $("#usernameLabel").show();
            $("#usernameField").show();
            $("#passwordLabel").show();
            $("#passwordField").show();
            //$("#initialCatalogLabel").hide();
            //$("#initialCatalogField").hide();

            document.getElementById("button1").textContent = "SQL Authentication";
            authType = 0;

        }
    });
});
```

```
<h2>Create</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>connection</legend>
   <div class="editor-label">
       Authentication Type
   </div>
   <div>
       <button id="button1" value="Intergrated" name="intergrated" >SQL Authentication</button>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        Connection Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.conName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.conName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
       Data Source
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataSource)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dataSource)
    </div>
     <div class="editor-label" id="initialCatalogLabel">
       Initial Catalog
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id="initialCatalogField"> 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.initialCatalog) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.initialCatalog)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label" id = "usernameLabel">
       Username
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id="usernameField">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" id = "passwordLabel">
       Password
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id = "passwordField">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
    </div>

   <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        @{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.error))
{
                <div style="color:Red">
                   @ViewBag.error 
                </div>           
}
        }
    </p>

</fieldset>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am struggling to see how to save a page state without making a session var

Using a view model to retain your information across post backs would do the trick.

```
public class ConnectionViewModel
{
    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    ...
}

public ActionResult Login()
{
    // pass in defaults 
    return View(new ConnectionViewModel
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Windows",
        ConnectionString = "..."
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(ConnectionViewModel viewModel)
{
    // pass view model back into view to retain values
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Yes I do think this would work, just thought I might have been missing something being new to MVC.. Thanks though